# How to register generic service

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am planning to move my system to generic service layer.

```
public interface IAbcService<TEntity> where TEntity : class

public class AbcService<TEntity> : IAbcService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

I tried something but it does not work.

```
services.AddTransient<typeof(IAbcService<MyEntity>), AbcService();
....
....
....
```

I'm using some of my entities and along with that I am trying to add it to properties.

How can I register a generic service in asp.net core?

Comment: If an answer met your needs, please mark it as accepted. If not, please comment on the answer or edit your question.

Answer (score 27):

I wanted to try the exact same thing before and I've got it to work like this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IAbcService<>), typeof(AbcService<>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IAbcService<Person>), typeof(AbcService<Person>));
```

Do mind the different structure, this is registering by parameters in a method.

To elaborate, as you can see in the example above, with the new DNX framework package we now can register both open and closed generics.
Try it out, both lines will work.

Comment: Love the first line of code as this allowed me to register the service for all descendants of "Person" (in this case) !!! Awesome!

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried

> services.AddTransient<IAbcService<>, AbcService>()

Comment: That won't compile. You have to use run-time `System.Type` instances via `typeof()` when referencing open generics.